# Android WebView upgrade/degrade issues

Tags: updates, webview

I'm using an Android application utilizing system WebView. After Android OTA upgrade up to 6.0.1, WebView's major version was 47. As far as I have had some issues with this version (specifically, webview sporadically hangs, and there is a similar issue logged - [Android WebView stops loading pages](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539373)), I decided to look for a fix.

According to [WebView beta community](https://plus.google.com/communities/105434725573080290360), there was available more recent release of 47 major version (47.0.2526.99) than I have had (I do not remember my former minor version exactly, but it was older than 47.0.2526.99). Then I decided to try to update webview in Google Play. Indeed it shown me that an update is available for System WebView and I made the update.

As a result I received "newer" WebView with major version 46! This is just illogical to me. So I'd like to know: *how is it possible to receive version updates which are downgrades in reality?*

Unfortunately, in this "new" version I encountered another bug similar to what described in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489259) ('javascript:' urls not working). So I'd like to make a rollback to my previous version. I noticed a menu in Google Play that says something about uninstalling the update for the webview. I clicked it, and as a result, I'm currently have webview with version 44!

Isn't this a mess? Shouldn't they prompt the user about exact version he will receive?

So the **main question is**: *how one can **ensure upgrade** to the latest stable (or, at least, specified) version?* If Google Play can provide outdated versions and even do not check if the device's already installed version is newer and overwrites it silently, then I just don't know what to think. Specifically I'd like to get the mentioned latest stable major version 47.

<sup>The 3-rd and the last question about the beta channel is voided now. It was absolutely unclear from the WebView Beta Community site, if stable WebView and beta WebView can live on the same device side by side, and if it is so, then how to embed one or another into an application. The answer is that installation of beta version means that the stable WebView will be replaced completely with the beta. This affects all applications using WebView, and this is definitely not how Chrome beta channel works (Chrome beta can work in parallel with stable versions and they do not interfere each other).</sup>

Comment: I'm sorry the question seemed too broad, but it was a single streamlined use-case, as you see: upgrade (the result is a mess), rollback (the result is even more mess). I'll edit just for clarity.

Comment: BTW, I don't remember I ever have had a notification about the question was closed. Not sure, if this is normal.

Comment: Did you leave the beta channel for WebView? If you left the beta channel, then Play Store will try to update (possibly downgrade) to the latest stable version. Otherwise, there might be a confusing version naming (alphanumeric) since Play Store and Android actually use version *code* (digit only) to decide the update. But to answer the main question: you can't. Play Store will only try to update to the latest version that is *compatible* (based on manifest and other Play Store filter) with your device. You can sideload the latest APK from alternative source manually though.

Comment: That said, [Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta) is not [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)'s beta channel, but a completely different app, so they can work in parallel. And also, OP is never notified when their question is closed/deleted.